# Trigonometry Identity (Proof): $ \sin^4\theta +\cos^4 \theta =1-2\sin^2 \theta \cos^2 \theta $

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

> > Question: Prove that  $$ \sin^4\theta +\cos^4 \theta =1-2\sin^2 \theta \cos^2 \theta $$

What I have attempted (Usually I start of with the complex side)

So starting with the LHS

$$ \sin^4\theta +\cos^4 \theta =1-2\sin^2 \theta \cos^2 \theta $$

$$ (\sin^2\theta)^2 + \cos^4 \theta =1-2\sin^2 \theta \cos^2 \theta $$

$$ (1-\cos^2\theta)^2 + \cos^4 \theta =1-2\sin^2 \theta \cos^2 \theta $$

$$ (1-\cos^2\theta)(1-\cos^2\theta) + \cos^4 \theta =1-2\sin^2 \theta \cos^2 \theta $$

$$ 1 - 2\cos^2\theta + \cos^4\theta + \cos^4\theta =1-2\sin^2 \theta \cos^2 \theta $$

$$ 1 - 2\cos^2\theta + 2\cos^4\theta  =1-2\sin^2 \theta \cos^2 \theta $$

Now I am stuck... is my approach correct?

Comment: I'd try substituting $(1-\cos^2\theta)$ for $\sin^2\theta$ in your last line, to get everything in terms of cosines. EDIT: Or, if you don't want to change the right hand side, factor out $2\cos^2\theta$ from two of the terms on the left.

Comment: Hint:

$\cos^4\theta+\sin^4\theta = (\cos^4\theta+2\sin^2\theta\cos^2\theta+\sin^4\theta) -2\sin^2\theta\cos^2\theta$

can you show that
$\cos^4\theta+2\sin^2\theta\cos^2\theta+\sin^4\theta = 1$?

Answer (score 4):

Alternatively, you may just **square** the identity

> $$
> \cos^2\theta +\sin^2 \theta=1
> $$

giving

$$
\cos^4\theta+2\cos^2\theta\sin^2\theta +\sin^4 \theta=1.
$$

Comment: But don't I have to use the identity given and manipulate it and thus prove it?

Comment: You are allowed to do so, but I don't know if your approach can lead easily to the answer.

Comment: @dydxx So take your identity, add $2\sin^2\theta\cos^2\theta$ to both sides, and factor the left hand side.